# is it possible to give states to compounddrawables of textview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one arrow image at rightside of textview.so i am using `android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"` and it works fine.
But I want that when textview is in selected state then i need to show arrow image else not.
is there any way that i can achieve it by selector.

can anybody tell me how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 7):

causing the following exception.

If you don't declare default state then selector  didn't work for me.so i have placed one transparent image in default state and it works for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/imagetrans"/>

</selector>
```

Usage:-

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtobject"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/selector"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="@string/object"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
```

Comment: Dear straya, I had tried <item android:drawable="@null" /> but it causing the above exception.Your answer didn't work for me then how can i accept this as a answer?If i accept this as an answer then many people who are using stackoverflow will be misleaded by me.

Comment: Dear straya,here we are to help our community so our aim should be help the community and not only reputation score.I appreciate your help but it didn't work for me.

Comment: <item android:drawable="@null" /> may cause the exception on selector item. And I could use `@android:color/transparent` with my own transparent image. But I couldn't make selector work on drawableRight(or drawableLeft). I ended up using selection image programmatically, `sortButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0, 0, R.drawable.name, 0);`